# Problems with changing .NET MVC project to point to new IIS site

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

So I am very new to web development and have a .NET MVC site that I have been working on. Unfortunately, Visual Studio removes most of the work in running a simple site in debug.  I am trying to learn about more of what gets generated when you build and fire up a website through Visual Studio so I can have more control over deploying additional sites.

**PROBLEM**

So in IIS I created a new site and defined the Site name, and pointed the physical path to the Web directory of my project (contains the web.config).

In Visual Studio, under the Web project properties changed
Start Action -> "Don't open a page, wait for request"
Servers -> "Use specific IIS web server" and specify the URL of the site name I defined in IIS (i.e. local.acme.com).

Cleaned solution, rebuilt and tried navigating to http://local.acme.com.  After getting past some original permissions issues (dir requiring permissions for IIS_USERs), it tries to automatically direct me to a view that doesn't exist:

**http://local.acme.com/Account/LogOn?ReturnUrl=%2f**

**NOTE** I created the project as a "EMPTY" MVC 2 Web application, so no default .NET MVC account view should exist.

Any thoughts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `web.config` . does it contain any entry for membership and authentication

An entry, something like this in `<system.web>`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Account/LogOn"  />
</authentication>
```

Comment: This is correct - does Visual Studio add this automatically?  Even for an 'empty' web MVC project?

Comment: Yes it does.. when you select a `MVC2 Web Application` in new project template it creates a default website which has authentication set to Forms by default and it also creates a Account controller for that.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<authentication>` element from Web.config.